# How to build Visual Basic (.vbp) project from AWS CodeBuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vb6, aws-codebuild

I want to build .vbp using AWS CodeBuild. I have setup CI/CD pipeline and now want to build the project using CodeBuild.

I Googled around and found that following command needs to be executed:

```
vbc.exe test.vbp
```

How to invoke this command from CodeBuild?

Comment: are u planning to build your project on linux mono or you want to use windows to build your visual basic project ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you planning on using a docker image provided by CodeBuild or do you have your own custom image?

Currently, the images provided by CodeBuild are geared for a specific programming language and/or stack.  Which means that they will only have specific tools pre-defined based on that selected image.  At this time, since there doesn't seem to be an image geared for classic visual basic, I think you would first need to install the compiler in the "install" phase of your build spec before you can build your source code.

Comment: I am not using any image. Whatever is default that I am using. In buildspec, do I need to copy the vbc.exe and then execute it as: vbc.exe test.vbp ?

Comment: When setting up a CodeBuild project you do have to select an operating system.  I am assuming that you are using the Windows Server Base.  The VB6 compiler will not be on the image by default, but you should be able to package up the exe in your source.  However, I am not sure if the vbc.exe calls additional programs while compiling or if that is a completely stand-alone exe.  If it is stand-alone it should work in theory.  I don't have the VB6 compiler to verify this, so it has not been tested from my end yet.

Comment: vbc.exe is a standalone program. I want to execute it as: vbc.exe test.vbp. To install vbc.exe in --install phase of buildspec.yml, where should I keep the actual vbc.exe? Do I need to bundle it in the artifact which is a .zip or in S3 bucket?

Comment: If it is a standalone exe, you should be able to run the program using the resolved location of the vbc.exe.  The "CODEBUILD_SRC_DiR" environment variable will be the path that contains the location of your source.  So for example if your source had a folder called "tools" off of your root and your exe was located there you could use "$env:CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR\tools\vbc.exe" to reference the path.  [CodeBuild Environment Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html).